# How to activate the MSSQL extension?

Tags: php, xampp

I'd like to use the PHP extension mssql. I've updated my `php.ini` and actived `php_mssql.dll`. After a restart of the Apache server, the browser tells me:

> **Fatal error:** Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in

The `phpinfo()` command shows the following configure command:

> cscript /nologo configure.js [...] **"--without-mssql"** [...]

How can I change this command or is this the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0):

The configure section of the phpinfo output shows, with which configuration directives your version of PHP was compiled with. You can't change these directives afterwards. In other words: the configure command just tells you, that your version of PHP was compiled without mssql.

You already tried the correct approach of enabling the extension.
Please try this again with a newer version of the extension and the driver.
You might find them over at Microsoft Download Center:

- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098
- https://github.com/azure/msphpsql